# Does the result of Derivatives have a place in their graphs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

For example, the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$. That means if $x=10$, then the derivative is $20$. How is this last number represented in the graph? Or, is it not supposed to have a role there?

Answer (score 1):

For a start derivatives don't necessitate having a graph any more than $x^2$ on its own constitutes a graph. If you have a graph I will take it there is two variables involved, say $y=x^2$. In this case the derivative $dy/dx = d(x^2)/dx = 2x$, represents the slope of the tangent to the graph at the point ($x$,$y$) with respect to the horizontal.

Comment: Okay! So the derivative is related to the tangent. Now that's illuminating. So the derivative is the slope of this tangent? Is so, how would, say, dY/dX = 10 describe that slope?

Comment: If you draw the tangent and make a right angled triangle from it (other sides being parallel to the axes) then you will find the ratio of the length of the vertical side to that of the horizontal side is dY:dX (for the case of dY/dX positive). dY/dX is described as rise over run, i.e. if you 'run' out dX (i.e. in the x direction), then you will 'rise' dY (in the y direction).

Comment: dY/dX=10 means that the slope will go up 10 units for every 1 unit across.

Comment: Thank you so much!!